# How to use imports globally in Vue-Application?

Tags: vue.js

I am teaching myself some Vue.js and after finding out about view-router I have to restructure my project.

How can I use my import (bulma, fontawesome, bulma-calendar...) in every view/component and import it only once?

I'd appreciate a hint. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if you want to use styles file globally you can import it inside your `App.vue` in style section.

```
<style lang="scss">
//your imports here
</style
```

If you want to import js files globally you can do it in your `main.js` file

In vue2 vue plugins are connected in this way:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import PluginName from "pulin-name";

Vue.use(PluginName);
```

For vue3 use:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import PluginName from "plugin-name";

const app = createApp(...);
app.use(PluginName);
```

Correct way should be described in plugin documentation, so read it before start to use in your project.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I looks like I did not hit the fine line between reading and starting this time.